# Regular Expression to match only all non-hidden graphic files

Tags: regex

I am writing a regular expression that should match some graphic files (non-hidden)
So I came up with the following expression

```
^[^\.][A-Za-z0-9]+(\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|tiff|tif|psd|eps|bmp))$
```

I am not sure how to include other characters in the `[A-Z.....]` bracket so that character like `-` or `_` would be included.

Comment: Why not just add these characters to the character class...? It's not clear what the problem you're having is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the dash and underscore to the character class. Character classes accept ranges as well as individual characters. Also, I added a `?:` to the group to make it non-capturing, and removed the parentheses around the period before the file suffix, since it's not necessary:

https://regex101.com/r/jrWpwL/1

`^[^\.][A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|tiff|tif|psd|eps|bmp)$`

Matches:

```
image.jpg
another-image.png
underscore_image.psd
```

Doesn't match:

```
image.txt
.hidden.pdf
```